# I randomly see a screaming seagull in the place of images in my browser

Tags: image, browser

This started about a month ago, that random images in my browser have been replaced by crazy things, usually a seagull picture. It is very distracting.

I've tried everything. Chrome, Firefox, Safari. I've cleared all my internet history.

Answer (score 0):

If you are SPECIFICALLY talking about a screaming seagull image, this is a well known virus. There is an image floating around the internet that appears like a benign animated GIF, but it contains meta code that is able to infect PCs via an instant messaging tool named Slack. It is most likely to happen with users that frequently use that emoji.

If you reinstall Slack it should clear out that cache and therefore the virus.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed I reinstalled Slack and my issue is resolved.